# Remove blank when slideToggle

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm working on a website and I've the following code :

```js
//SlideToggle
$('a').attr('href', 'javascript:void(0)');
$('a').click(function() {
  $(this).next().slideToggle();
});

$('.container div').addClass('cf');
```

```css
.hidden {
  display: none;
}
.container {
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
.container div {
  width: 25%;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
  text-align: center;
  background: lightblue;
  margin: 0 0 0.25em;
  padding: 25px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <div><a href="#">See more</a>
    <p class="hidden">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Quia ipsam, dolorem illum. Amet officiis dignissimos eligendi excepturi nam, aliquid architecto atque nostrum illo. Ratione nesciunt, id nulla dolores? Blanditiis, praesentium.</p>
  </div>
  <div><a href="#">See more</a>
    <p class="hidden">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Error sint nihil labore molestias expedita corrupti ipsa iusto iure sit nisi ab nobis maxime unde voluptates magni, distinctio quae. Deserunt, incidunt.</p>
  </div>
  <div><a href="#">See more</a>
    <p class="hidden">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Deserunt accusamus facilis tempore repellat eligendi accusantium laudantium quis, magni a soluta deleniti voluptatibus quam, est aliquid. Atque a, esse. Itaque, consequuntur.</p>
  </div>
  <div><a href="#">See more</a>
    <p class="hidden">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Aperiam, quo, possimus. Quam odit laudantium, ex alias, repellat laborum quae nobis expedita aperiam iusto iure at facilis obcaecati doloribus quis earum.</p>
  </div>
  <div><a href="#">See more</a>
    <p class="hidden">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Quam ratione doloribus laborum deleniti quae cumque quasi, repellat, ex nemo nulla corporis voluptatum vel doloremque nesciunt cupiditate, veritatis excepturi vero harum.</p>
  </div>
  <div><a href="#">See more</a>
    <p class="hidden">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Aliquam cupiditate quisquam, dicta eligendi ut eos culpa nisi quod nesciunt vero soluta voluptates illo esse voluptatibus, ab, sint impedit repudiandae dolorum!</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

The slideToggle is working well . However, when I slideToggle, I want this action only affect the div at the bottom and not the others. Let me show you what I want :

[image]

**(I don't want to touch at div height, they have to stay like that)**

Hope I'm clear. Thanks for your help !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This comes close, maybe someone is able to improve this..

```js
//SlideToggle
 $('a').attr('href','javascript:void(0)');
 $('a').click(function() { 
       var $self = $(this);
       var index = $self.parent().index();     
  $(this).next().slideToggle(100, function() {           
            var margin = $self.parent().toggleClass("active").find("p").outerHeight();   
            if($self.parent().hasClass("active")) {
                 $(".container div").eq(index + 3).css("margin-top", margin);   
            }
             else {
                $(".container div").eq(index + 3).css("margin-top", 0);            
            }                     
        });         
 });
 $('.container div').addClass('cf');
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing:border-box;
  }

.hidden {
  display: none;
}

.container {
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.container div {
  width: 33.3333333333%;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
  text-align: center;
  background: lightblue;
  margin:0;
  padding: 25px;
  position:relative;
  -webkit-transition: ease-in-out, margin .1s ease-in-out;
  transition: ease-in-out, margin .1s ease-in-out;
  float:left;
}

.container div p {
  position:absolute;
  width:100%;
 left:0;
  padding:25px;
  margin:0;
  top:100%;
  background: lightblue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <div><a href="#">See more</a>
    <p class="hidden">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Quia ipsam, dolorem illum. Amet officiis dignissimos eligendi excepturi nam, aliquid architecto atque nostrum illo. Ratione nesciunt, id nulla dolores? Blanditiis, praesentium.</p>
  </div>
  <div><a href="#">See more</a>
    <p class="hidden">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Error sint nihil labore molestias expedita corrupti ipsa iusto iure sit nisi ab nobis maxime unde voluptates magni, distinctio quae. Deserunt, incidunt.</p>
  </div>
  <div><a href="#">See more</a>
    <p class="hidden">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Deserunt accusamus facilis tempore repellat eligendi accusantium laudantium quis, magni a soluta deleniti voluptatibus quam, est aliquid. Atque a, esse. Itaque, consequuntur.</p>
  </div>
  <div><a href="#">See more</a>
    <p class="hidden">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Aperiam, quo, possimus. Quam odit laudantium, ex alias, repellat laborum quae nobis expedita aperiam iusto iure at facilis obcaecati doloribus quis earum.</p>
  </div>
  <div><a href="#">See more</a>
    <p class="hidden">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Quam ratione doloribus laborum deleniti quae cumque quasi, repellat, ex nemo nulla corporis voluptatum vel doloremque nesciunt cupiditate, veritatis excepturi vero harum.</p>
  </div>
  <div><a href="#">See more</a>
    <p class="hidden">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Aliquam cupiditate quisquam, dicta eligendi ut eos culpa nisi quod nesciunt vero soluta voluptates illo esse voluptatibus, ab, sint impedit repudiandae dolorum!</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

Hide all the p tag before do Slide toggle.

```
$('a').click(function() {
        $('p').hide(); 
        $(this).next().slideToggle(); 
});
```